# MDX: Filter a Dimension on its properties

Tags: filter, mdx, dimension, iccube, iccube-reporting

I want to filter a dimension on its properties.
My Dimension consists of various categories with parent Leaf-categories.  Each Category has an online status (true or false). Within the dimension I define the property "is_online".
Now I want to filter the category-tree by status `[is_online] = true`

My current MDX is:

```
SELECT
  FILTER(
    [Categories].allmembers,
    [categories].CurrentMember.properties("is_online") = 'true' 
  ) on 0
FROM [Cube]
```

I get this error:

```
Property(): the property 'is_online' was not found
```

Does anyone know a solution? My Version of IcCube is V 5.1.6

[Dimension & Property definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItsyW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need another `[categories]` for it to function?

```
SELECT
  FILTER(
    [Categories].allmembers,
    [Categories].[Categories].CurrentMember.properties("is_online") = 'true' 
  ) on 0
FROM [Cube];
```

Maybe HAVING helps:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[online] AS 
    [categories].currentmember.Properties('is_online') 
SELECT 
  [categories].ALLMEMBERS HAVING 
  [Measures].[online] = 'True' ON 0
 ,[Measures].[online] ON 1
FROM [Cube];
```

Answer (score 0):

A member of `[Categories].allmembers` is missing the property "is_online".

My educated guess would be the [All] member that if default has no user defined properties.

Maybe something like :

```
SELECT
 FILTER(
  [Categories].allmembers,
  [Categories].CurrentMember.isAll = false 
  AND
  [Categories].CurrentMember.properties("is_online") = 'true' 
  ) on 0
FROM [Cube]
```

We'll improve the error message in the following version ([issues](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-217))

Comment: here, too. I get the same Error: the property is not found

Comment: you've a debugger in icCube, have you tried to used it ?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old post.
Please try replacing the _ in the property name with a space. Eg: "is online".